# I need to replace one cell with another in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to replace one cell of a row with another cell of same row in pandas data frame[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6eRMo.jpg)

Comment: Historie will be replace by  ''1.) "Verein Technologietransfer Handwerk" (Stiftung Adalbert- Seifriz-Preis) e.V.''

Comment: and '' 1.) "Verein Technologietransfer Handwerk" (Stiftung Adalbert- Seifriz-Preis) e.V.'' will be replace by Stuttgart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can solve your specific problem:

```
df.iloc[4,3] = df.iloc[4,2]
df.iloc[4,2] = df.iloc[4,1]
```

Cannot say more without knowing what you're actually trying to do

Comment: thank you so much. I finally figure it out. But having another problem . In my data frame I have different city name, Like: 'Stittgart', Munich...etc. Some of the city are like             
'1) Stuttgart' that. I have use this code     for x in prep_table1['Sitz']:
    list_x = x.split(')')
    if len(list_x) == 1: 
        prep_table1['New_sitz'] = list_x[0]
    elif len(list_x) == 2: 
        prep_table1['New_sitz'] = list_x[1]
    else:
        prep_table1['New_sitz'] = list_x[2]   but it only filled with 'March'. By the way last row has 1.) March. How can I solve this prob.